# Can't Upload Image with Google Photos API using NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-photos-api

I have application built in NodeJS it is suppose to upload pictures to google photos using google photos API
for the authentication part I'm doing successfully, i have problem when i try to upload pictures i receive the upload token without problem but when i try to use mediaItems:batchCreate it returns :

```
"status": {
    "code": 3,
    "message": "Failed: There was an error while trying to create this media item."
  }
```

Here is my code to convert the image into base64 :

```
var base64str = fs.readFileSync('1.jpg', 'base64');
```

And here is the request where i get response the upload token :

```
request({
method: 'post',
headers: {
'content-type' : 'application/octet-stream',
'Authorization': `Bearer ${userToken}`,
'X-Goog-Upload-File-Name' :  '1.jpg',
'X-Goog-Upload-Protocol' : 'raw'
},
url: `https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com/v1/uploads`,
rejectUnauthorized: false,
body: base64str
}, function(err,response,body) {
      console.log(body);
      });
```

Up to here i don't have issue because (body) response is the upload token and i receive it.
now when i want to go to step#2 to request the mediaItems:batchCreate  here is the code :

```
let reqObject = {
    newMediaItems: [
      {
        description: "Test Image Uploading",
        simpleMediaItem: {
        uploadToken: body //Body is the upload token received from prev request
        }
      }
    ]
  };
let reqObjectString = JSON.stringify(reqObject);

  request({
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
    'content-type' : 'application/json',
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${userToken}`,
    },
    url: `https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com/v1/mediaItems:batchCreate`,
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
    body: reqObjectString
  }, function(err,response,result) {
      console.log(result);
});
```

The Expected Result here it's suppose to be the successful uploading media but instead i always get this respons :

```
{
  "newMediaItemResults": [
    {
      "uploadToken": "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",      
        "status": {
        "code": 3,
        "message": "Failed: There was an error while trying to create this media item."
      }
```

Can anyone help, thanks in advance

Comment: The same issue here. I look forward for Google engineer support. https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/117437699

Comment: @FrancisRodrigues thanks for sharing, i solved my problem that i mentioned above through changing the this code fs.readFileSync('1.jpg', 'base64') into 'binary' instead of base64 as google only accepts binary for this api method , try it

Comment: Can you share how you managed to get the initial upload to work? I'm using the [googlephotos](https://github.com/roopakv/google-photos#readme) module and am stuck with a "Authentication session is not defined" error.

Comment: @Michael hi, i solved the code above error with using  fs.readFileSync('1.jpg', 'binary') so that will fit with google api request, i hope this is the answer for your problem otherwise can you share your question in full details then i can support if i know

Answer (score 0):

Your comment is absolutely correct. The google photos API expects media in binary format and not in base64 format.

I was using React.js and FileReader to read the media. I had to use:

```
const reader = new FileReader()
reader.readAsArrayBuffer()
```

to get the array buffer and then the image got successfully uploaded.